# Magento 2: Deleting all products via SQL

Tags: magento2, product

Is it still possible to delete all producs in Magento 2 using:

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity`;
```

Will it still clean all other tables that have product data because of the foreign key constraints? What about the URL rewrites, will that also be cleaned?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899366/deleting-all-products-on-magento describes how to do it for Magento 1.

Answer (score 0):

You will  run delete query on `catalog_product_entity` table then below tables record will be deleted as **entity** column of `catalog_product_entity`  is be related using the foreign keys:

```
catalog_category_product
catalog_compare_item
catalog_product_bundle_option
catalog_product_bundle_price_index
catalog_product_bundle_selection
catalog_product_entity_datetime
catalog_product_entity_decimal
catalog_product_entity_gallery
catalog_product_entity_int
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity
catalog_product_entity_text
catalog_product_entity_tier_price
catalog_product_entity_varchar
catalog_product_frontend_action
catalog_product_index_tier_price
catalog_product_link
catalog_product_link
catalog_product_option
catalog_product_relation
catalog_product_relation
catalog_product_super_attribute
catalog_product_super_link
catalog_product_super_link
catalog_product_website
catalog_url_rewrite_product_category
cataloginventory_stock_item
downloadable_link
downloadable_sample
product_alert_price
product_alert_stock
report_compared_product_index
report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily
report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly
report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly
report_viewed_product_index
weee_tax
wishlist_item
```

[image]

But other tables on which product id  save like **sales_order** does not delete, you will run delete query on `catalog_product_entity`

**See:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column